# RESTful WebServices: PUT, POST and DELETE - where to put the parameters

Tags: rest, http

I would have a question concerning the properties which will be transfered from client to server. 
HTTP GET is clear: Parameters are transmitted in URL and not in body!

HTTP PUT: where to transmit parameters - in URL or Body?

HTTP POST: where to transmit parameters - in URL or Body?

HTTP DELETE: where to transmit parameters - in URL or Body?

Thanks a ot for answering the question!

Answer (score 0):

The id of the entity in PUT (update) and DELETE request should be in the url. The entity to update in PUT requests should be in the body. The entity to create in POST requests should also be in the body.

Optional parameters should be sent in query string. Other contextual information on the entity (Composite id) should be in the url.